# Rock, paper, scissors computer decision based on player decision python

Tags: python, if-statement, boolean-logic

> So I'm trying again with no results. I think it looks better this time but the biased choice still needs some fixes. It is still just giving me random options. Also sometimes when i give 'p' as an option it doesn't do anything except ask if I want to play again. Any help is appreciated!

```
    #Making a game of rock, paper, scissors
```

> All the inputs/results are located

```
# Player and computer score starting at 0
#I also print the number of times that the player picks rock, paper , or scissors and print it
computer_wins = 0
player_wins = 0
player_rock = 0
player_paper = 0
player_scissor = 0
import random
from random import randint

#getting the result from the player
```

> Where the player makes a choice

```
    def the_game():
        choice = input("Pick between Rock (r), Paper(p), Scissors(s):  ").lower()
        global player_rock
        global player_paper
        global player_scissor
        if choice == 'r':
            Rchoice = 'r'
            player_rock +=1
        elif choice == 'p':
            Pchoice = 'p'
            player_paper +=1
        elif choice == 's':
            Schoice = 's'
            player_scissor += 1
        else:
            print("That is not a valid option, please try again.")
            the_game()
        return choice

# Get the result from the computer
```

> Computer making a random choice

```
    def comp_choice():
        c_choice = random.randint(1,3)
        if c_choice == 1:
            c_choice = 'r'
        elif c_choice == 2:
            c_choice = 'p'
        elif c_choice == 3:
            c_choice = 's'
        return c_choice

#Making the computer choose based on players decisions
```

> Computer making a biased choice based on the play inputs (where I am having trouble).

```
def biased_choice():
    Rchoice =  player_rock
    Pchoice =  player_paper
    Schoice =  player_scissor
    if Rchoice > (Pchoice and Schoice):
        bias_choice = 'p'

    elif Pchoice > (Rchoice and Schoice):
        bias_choice = 's'

    elif Schoice > (Rchoice and Pchoice):
        bias_choice = 'r'
    else:
        bias_choice = comp_choice()

    return bias_choice
```

> Where the game is play. Sometimes when I put in 'p' it will skip the game entirely and just ask if I want to play again. Anything helps

```
while True:

    player_choice = the_game()
    computer_choice = biased_choice()

    if player_choice == 'r':
        if computer_choice == 'r':
            print("You both chose rock. You tied. Try again. \n")
        elif computer_choice == 'p':
            print("You chose rock and lost to paper. \n")
            computer_wins += 1
        elif computer_choice == 's':
            print("You chose rock and won! \n")
            player_wins += 1
        print("Player wins: " + str(player_wins))
        print("Computer wins:  " + str(computer_wins))

        player_choice = input("Do you want to play again? (y/n) \n")
        if player_choice == 'y':
            pass
        elif player_choice == 'n':
            break
        else:
            print("Invalid choice! Thanks for playing!")
            break

    elif player_choice == 'p':
        if computer_choice == 'p':
            print("You both chose paper. You tied. Try again. \n")
        elif computer_choice == 's':
            print("You chose paper and lost to scissors. \n")
            computer_wins += 1
        elif computer_choice == 'p':
            print("You chose paper and won!!! \n")
            player_wins += 1
        print("Player wins: " + str(player_wins))
        print("Computer wins:  " + str(computer_wins))

        player_choice = input("Do you want to play again? (y/n) \n")
        if player_choice == 'y':
            pass
        elif player_choice == 'n':
            break
        else:
            print("Invalid choice! Thanks for playing!")
            break


    elif player_choice == 's':
        if computer_choice == 's':
            print("You both chose scissors. You tied. Try again. \n")
        elif computer_choice == 'r':
            print("You chose scissors and lost to rock.\n")
            computer_wins += 1
        elif computer_choice == 'p':
            print("You chose scissors and won! \n")
            player_wins += 1


        print("Player wins: " + str(player_wins))
        print("Computer wins:  " + str(computer_wins))

        player_choice = input("Do you want to play again? (y/n) \n")
        if player_choice == 'y' or 'Y':
            pass
        elif player_choice == 'n':
            break
        else:
            print("Invalid choice! Thanks for playing!")
            break
```

Comment: Please be more clear on what exactly is it that you require and what is corrently not working (maybe error messages or any desired behavior examples)

Comment: Okay so to be clear the computer still gives me random choices no matter what my inputs have been. So if I choose paper the most, the computer will still choose between random and not give me paper like I want it too.

Comment: there are mistakes, in your code for eg: when player chooses p there is no clause for computer choosing r. Clean up your code add the decision making as another function, leave the main loop only for reading input and the continue option that will help

Comment: Wow @Vikash B thank you so much that little error solved everything because now it works to perfection. I'm embarrassed yet happy it is done with. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you are making a biased choice using random numbers you need a way of understanding how the decision space is divided up. Conceptually, you can think of this as a roulette wheel with different sections marked out for each random choice. If you have 3/4 of the roulette wheel marked for one choice and 1/4 marked for the other choice, you will more likely end up with the first one.

So, for this simplistic example, you take your `random.random()` which will give you a floating point number between 0 and 1. If the value is less than 0.75, you get the first choice, otherwise the second one. Apply this concept to your code and you're good to go.